# Attach two success functions to an AJAX call (for queueing purposes)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a queue script that queues commands being sent to an API through an AJAX call. These calls can not be called asynchronously, they have to be executed in the order they occur.

Right now I'm just preparing data for an AJAX call and then pushing that data on an array. Then I start making the actual AJAX call. As soon as it's done I want to execute the original success-function, but I also want to launch the next item in the queue... The code I have:

```
var queue = [];
function add( call ){
  queue.push( call );

  if( queue.length == 1 )
     launch();
}

function launch(){
   if( !queue.length ) return;

   $.ajax( call );
}
```

To initiate an AJAX call (this is inside the form's submit function):

```
var data = new Formdata( $("#theform")[0] );
add( {
   data: data,
   success: function( fb ){
       console.log( fb );
   }
});
```

The problem I'm running in to now is that the AJAX call will call the success function I pushed onto the array, but I want to attach a second function that does another call to 'launch' in case there is another call pushed onto the queue before the first call was done. I do need the calls to be made in the same order they're executed. So the first item in the queue should only be removed once the previous AJAX calls have been finished. I have different forms initiating the AJAX calls, so the success function is different for each call. So: in this second call I would love to execute:

```
queue.shift();  // to remove the call that just finished
launch();       // to start executing the next call
```

How can I call the launch() function again once the AJAX call was successful, or do I need to add the code (shift and launch) to every success-function I push on the queue? That would work, but looks rather messy to me.

Comment: Where do you actually call `add()`? Is this in a loop somewhere? Or just gets called at random times based on events/triggers in the app?

Comment: It seems like you should be calling `add()` in the callback. Though there's no real problem simply adding both `queue.shift()` and `launch()` to the callback.

Comment: @charlietfl add() gets called whenever a form is submitted or another action is done. Basically every action a user makes on the website has to be recorded to a database in the order the user made the actions. The second block of code in the example has that code, there are more than just that form on the site

Comment: @ObsidianAge: there are more than one form making the need for an AJAX call. Somehow adding the shift and launch to every one of these functions seems a bit obsolete in terms of data abstraction... every form then has queue stuff in their success form, I want to keep that neatly inside the AJAX queue code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to do something like:

```
function launch(){
   if( !queue.length ) return;

   var call = queue[0];
   $.ajax( call ).done( function(){
       queue.shift();
       launch();
   });
}
```

Note you will need to also consider error handling

Comment: Won't that launch the 'done' as soon as AJAX called is fire, and not after the 'success' function has been called?

Comment: Actually be better to use `then()` instead of success and done(). But no...`done()` fires after request completes

Comment: Yes, this launches after the AJAX call returns indeed! And it calls the original 'success' function in the call. So this is exactly what I needed. 

error handling is a good point indeed. If there is an error at some point in this case it's important not to let subsequent actions launch. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Have never used it but there is also a `always()` method that should run regardless of status. If it is a failed request it gets arguments the same as `error`. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The queue.shift() should actually also be called in the 'done' (or then), otherwise a new launch will initiate if first AJAX call is initiated and a second call is added. The second call must only be initiated once the first is finished.. I'll edit your answer to fix this problem

Comment: If I call 'add' before a first call is finished, then that will initiate an AJAX call straight after queueing it. I want it to wait 'till after the first call is completely finished. The function 'add' will call launch() straight away if you shift the call off the array before it's finished...

Comment: Also seems like should just be checking any length inside `add()` but starting to see the issue. Might need a flag for a call in progress

Comment: No, it should only call 'launch' when the length is one (meaning it's the first item pushed on the array). If a second call is added it will have to wait for the 'launch' in the callback function inside your $.ajax().done function. That will launch the subsequent calls 'till they're all done. If the queue is empty it will stop making calls until the user pushed a call again, in which case the length is 1 and we need to force 'launch' after pushing the call onto the array.

Comment: Ok...got it. Haven't thought this all the way through or tried it myself